# Translation morphism of abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am new to study of abelian varieties. But I need it in my work. Let $X$ be a ppav, say a Jacobian of a genus 2 curve. Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$.

The set $K(L)=\{x\in X : T_x^* L\simeq L\}$ is a finite set since $L$ is ample.

1) By theorem of square, if $x\in K(L)$, all multiples are in $K(L)$ also. How is this possible. Does it mean $K(L)$ consist of only torsion elements?

2) Does $K(L)$ act on $|L|$? Take curve $C\in |L|$ then $C-x\in |L|$ right? What can we say about this action?

Comment: The answers to both questions are "yes".

Comment: @Jason Starr, thank you. What is the orbit of a curve $C$?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the orbit of a curve $C$?"  For a generic choice of divisor in the linear system of $|L|$, $K(L)$ will act freely with trivial stabilizer and with orbit of cardinality $\# K(L)$.  Is that what you are asking?  There can be divisors with nontrivial stabilizer, e.g., the flex lines to a fixed plane cubic $X$ in $|L|=\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @Jason Starr, thank you, that is what I wanted to know. Is there some reference to this?

Comment: "Is there some reference to this?"  Example 9.3, p. 141, of Igor Dolgachev, "Lectures on Invariant Theory".

Comment: When I wrote "flex lines" above, I should have written "secant lines of two distinct flex points".